# ADO on Access Lookup field, getting wrong field returned

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, dao

I'm in Excel 2010 VBA, using ADO 2.8 to query an Access 2010 database. I don't own the database and don't have any authority to make any changes to it. I've been working with Excel VBA for many years but my Access knowledge is sketchy.

Using the same SQL as one of the queries in the database (copied from the Access query and pasted into Excel VBA), I get different results in some fields than that query in the database gets.

For the affected fields, I see that in Access those fields are defined as lookups. Here's an example lookup from one of the affected fields' Row Source property:

```
SELECT [Signers].[SignerID], [Signers].[SignerName] FROM Signers ORDER BY [SignerID], [SignerName];
```

In the Access database, where the SQL statement refers to that field, the query returns SignerName.

But in my ADO code, where the very same SQL statement refers to that field, the query returns SignerID, not SignerName.

Is there something I can do from my ADO code to get SignerName instead of SignerID, from the same SQL statement? Or do I need to modify the SQL statement?

Thanks,

Greg

Update:

On the Access side, I think I see now why only SignerName appears. On the field's Lookup tab, the Column Widths property is:

0";1.2605"

So I guess SignerID is there in the Access query result but with a column width of 0.

Unfortunately that doesn't help me on the ADO side. Any suggestions on getting SignerName instead of SignerID in the ADO query result?

Update2:

Here's a sample SQL statement that returns different fields depending on either it's in Access or in ADO:

```
SELECT MasterAccount.[SignerKey1] 
FROM MasterAccount ;
```

Per Preet's request, here's the ADO code in Excel VBA:

```
strDatabasePath = rgDatabasePathCell.Value 'rgDatabasePathCell is a worksheet cell object.
strPWD = DATABASE_PASSWORD

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & strDatabasePath & "';Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & strPWD & "';"
cnn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

rst.Open cmd.Execute

shMA.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst 'shMA is a worksheet object.
```

Update 3:

It occurred to me that from what I've said so far, it might seem like I could just change this:

```
SELECT MasterAccount.[SignerKey1] 
FROM MasterAccount ;
```

to this:

```
SELECT [Signers].[SignerName] 
FROM MasterAccount ;
```

But there are 13 affected lookup fields, all with exactly the same "Row Source" property text as shown above, and all return different SignerName items for each row. I don't know why they are all returning different items per row; I have not been able to find any difference in the way they are defined. I've been tasked with getting the same result in Excel as that Access query gets.

Update 4:

VBlades -- Thanks, I found the form that has a tab with dropdowns for each of the 13 SignerKey-n fields. If I right-click that form and choose Form Properties, the RecordSource property is:

```
SELECT MasterAccount.*, Bank.BankRating FROM Bank INNER JOIN MasterAccount ON Bank.BankID = MasterAccount.Bank;
```

However I don't understand how that would be selecting a different SignerName item for each of the 13 SignerKey-n fields, or what to do with this information to get the same results in ADO as in the Access query. Any suggestions?

Update 5:

I may be close to a workaround. If I do this, I get the SignerName field for SignerKey1:

```
SELECT Signers.SignerName
FROM Signers RIGHT JOIN MasterAccount ON Signers.SignerID = MasterAccount.SignerKey1.Value;
```

And if I do this, I get different SignerName items for each field on each row:

```
SELECT Signers.SignerName, Signers_1.SignerName, Signers_2.SignerName
FROM Signers AS Signers_2 INNER JOIN (Signers AS Signers_1 INNER JOIN (Signers RIGHT JOIN MasterAccount ON Signers.SignerID = MasterAccount.SignerKey1.Value) ON Signers_1.SignerID = MasterAccount.SignerKey2.Value) ON Signers_2.SignerID = MasterAccount.SignerKey3;
```

That works both in an Access query and in ADO. Next step, I'll try to add these joins to the main SQL statement.

Update 6:

Well, when I try to add even one of those 13 joins to the main SQL statement, it works fine in an Access query, but in ADO I get the error:

Row handles must all be released before new ones can be obtained.

So I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

I've raised the issue with the database owner, but they don't know why the affected fields' Row Source property includes SignerID, so I'm not sure if that's going to help.

Comment: Any chance you can put both sets of code here please?

Comment: Hi Preet -- do you mean the SQL statement? I've added a sample above.

Comment: Hi Preet. I've added the ADO code from Excel VBA. There is no DAO code. There is no code on the Access side; it's just a query in Access.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder... perhaps if you tried the following: Write some DAO code in vba and verify that you get the same data on each row/column as the Ado? Then perhaps repeat the test in from another Vba app- say another instance of Access? What I'm thinking is that it's not an DAO/ADO issue rather something in how Access is internally issuing the query. Also I see you've added another query. Can you repeat the error with a fresh Access DB and say sample data?

Comment: Hi Preet -- Thanks, but I don't understand what this has to do with DAO. There is no DAO code. There is ADO code in Excel VBA, and there is an Access query (no code other than the SQL statement; just a query in Access). Rather than spend time rewriting the ADO code as legacy DAO code, I'm going to try rewriting the SQL statement to avoid the lookup columns.

Comment: I know Greg. What I was suggesting was to extract the core of the problem out side of that particular Access db such that you could determine if that db, or Access was the problem or whether the provider was the problem. Either way good luck

Comment: @GregLovern: The SQL in the RowSource property of the field in question is just a bucket list of all the possible selections - it's just a picklist.  The SignerID is the bound column from what you found out about the column widths - that means, for each record, there will be table which contains the SignerID for each row of the form's dataset (thus different SignerNames).  If you dig into the properties of the form that field sits on, and go to the Data tab, and look at RecordSource, you will see a query or SQL string.  Look into the query or the SQL to see what the big picture dataset is.

Comment: SQL is SQL. It doesn't matter where you execute it from - it will return the same fields. I don't think you are looking at the right areas in the database. You need to figure out which fields you do actually want returned, which table(s) they are in, and then create the appropriate SQL. It's impossible to do that remotely without knowing the database layout.

Comment: VBlades -- thanks, answer in Update 4 above.

Comment: Rory, I thought so too before seeing this issue. But with exactly the same SQL statement, I'm getting different results depending on whether I'm in an Access query or in ADO. I'm not doing anything remotely; I have full access to a local copy of the database. However, it won't help to try to resolve the problem by making changes to the Access database, because ultimately this needs to work when querying against the live copy of the database, over which I have no control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I worked around the problem by getting a separate recordset of the SignerID and SignerName fields from the Signers table.

Then I looped through all the rows of each affected field, looked up SignerID in the 2nd table, and swapped in SignerName for SignerID in the original table.

I tried to do that in ADO, but got the error "An UPDATE or DELETE query cannot contain a multi-valued field". So instead I made the swaps after copying the recordset to the Excel worksheet.

I would have liked to know how to handle it all in ADO, but this works. All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (simplest way)

Exclude `[Signers].[SignerID]` from the Query

```
SELECT [Signers].[SignerName] FROM Signers ORDER BY [SignerID], [SignerName];
```

Or, create Composite field containing both `[SignerID]`, [SignerName] and extract any part using VBA that you are familiar with:

```
 SELECT ([SignerID] & "_" & [SignerName]) As Composite FROM Signers ORDER BY [SignerID], [SignerName]
```

Regards,

Comment: Alex -- thanks, but I have no control over the Access database, so I can't exclude the [Signers].[SignerID], which is in the "Row Source" property of the affected lookup fields, in the Access database. I can control  the SQL statement I use in my ADO code from Excel VBA, but [Signers].[SignerID] does not appear there.